# How do I install Peazip? [dependencies not satisfiable]

Tags: dependencies

I want to try this archiver, since I cant seem to drag srt files to VLC from file roller. But I get this error when trying to install the .deb

[image: error picture]

I use Lubuntu 14.04 LTS
I tried installing QT version but that brings up a different error.

Comment: I know I can just open, but I want to be able to drag from the zip window to VLC, I'm more used to it and its faster.

Comment: QT seems to be fine, can you type show what error you get when installing QT version?

Answer (score 1):

The GTK version complains about dependency problems.
Try to install the QT version of 32 bits from [Peazip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html). It installs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both GTK and Qt deb installation files (PeaZip 5.6.1) reported a dependencies issue and a bad package quality respectively. But there is no need to install application, rather use a portable GTK version [x32](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html) or [x86-64](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux-64.html).

**To integrate** portable PeaZip to nautilus:

1) copy desirable scripts from

> FreeDesktop_integration/nautilus-scripts/Archiving/PeaZip

folder to your nautilus scripts folder.

2) right click on binary file `peazip` and make a link

3) copy link to `/usr/local/bin` and rename it to `peazip`.

Now you will have PeaZip options in nautilus context-menu.